# Specifying string fields length on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm not able to generate string fields with a specified length in a migration. They are always created with 255 character-length.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `:limit` option:

```
class CreateUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name, :limit => 10
    end
  end
end
```

[Reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition/column)